# Redirect works fine but I get File does not exist in logs

Tags: .htaccess

I have this .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^user/([_.0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ show-user.php?user=$1 [L]
```

which redirects just fine in the browser, but if on the error log on my server I can see hundreds of "File does not exist" errors, do you have any idea why?

Here is an error example from the log:

```
[Thu Mar 28 02:58:43 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] File does not exist: /home/folder/public_html/user, referer: domain/user/username0001
```

And there are hundreds! But everything works fine! What can I do to make these errors not show up?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, I had to use /show-user.php like this

```
RewriteRule ^user/([_.0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ /show-user.php?user=$1 [L]
```